# Constrained sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Consider the Sobolev space  $W^{1,2}([0,1])$.

If I am not mistaken this space admits an orthonormal basis:

$1, 2\pi n\sqrt{2} \cos(2\pi n x), 2\pi n\sqrt{2} \sin(2\pi n x), \quad n= 1,2,...$

Now I impose two constrains, namely $u(0)=0$ and $u(1)=0$, $\forall u \in W^{1,2}([0,1])$.

Can you provide an orthonormal basis for the new constrained space?

In general, what can be said about this new space?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No, we have $W^{0,2} = L^2$ by definition. Functions from Sobolev spaces may not be continuous. And your $U$ is not complete, but every Sobolev space is complete.

Comment: @gerw I have edited the question, does it make more sense now ?

Comment: @Martin Väth  Hi Martin you have commented to a similar question I asked before, I am trying to find a space where this question makes sense, I think I found it, any thoughts ?

Comment: Yes, now this question makes sense. However, your sequence is no longer normalized (for computing the $H^1$ norm, you have to take the derivative and this yields another factor of $2 \pi n$ in front of each term).

Comment: @gerw Better  now?

Comment: No. Did you actually try to compute the norm?